# Best time of the day to release Android app for US market

Tags: android, download, release, google-play

One question was asked on stackoverflow about which time of the day is the best to release an Android app. The answer was 16.22 GMT.
[Best time/day to publish to Android Market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452883/best-time-day-to-publish-to-android-market)

My App is 95% aimed at the US market, what would be the best time to release an app for the US Market?

Did someone do any studies about this ?

Comment: Who is your target market/demographic? What time of day are your users most likely to use the app? If you're worrying about what time of day to release, I suspect that you may have a bug in your `marketing strategy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saw something that said Sunday was.

http://techcrunch.com/2011/12/19/sunday-is-the-best-day-to-launch-your-mobile-app/

Comment: See also: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/12/closer-look-at-10-billion-downloads.html